# How to replace occurrence of a particular string by reading values from another and creating different files

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am a newbie and trying to achieve something like below. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
File 1:
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
```

```
File 2:
This is the first line:
This is the 2nd line: Some Text Some Text A=XXX
This is the 3rd line: Some Text Some
This is the 4th line: Some Text Some K_XXX Some Text Some 
This is the 5th line: DXXX
```

I want to write a script which will take arguments from File1 one by one and replace that with all the occurances of XXX in File2 and then create new files as given below:

File2_AAA.txt (Contains everything from File2 with XXX replaced by AAA)

File2_BBB.txt (Contains everything from File2 with XXX replaced by BBB)

File2_CCC.txt (Contains everything from File2 with XXX replaced by CCC)
.
.

ETC

I have written the below code but it doesn't seem to work

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do

   sed -i 's/\bXXX\b/"$line"/g' file2.txt 
done < file1.txt
```

Comment: You are still inside single qoutes. Close single quotes, then start double quotes. `'s/....'"$line"'/g'`

Comment: I am not getting the desired output even after making this modification and also no new files are getting generated.

Comment: Don't use option `-i` (in-place editing)  if you want to create new files. Redirect the output to `> "file2_${line}.txt"`.

Comment: Thank you Bodo. 

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified version of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
  sed "s/\bXXX\b/$line/g" < file2.txt > "File2_$line.txt"
done < file1.txt
```

With `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` defined as in your question, it writes `File2_AAA.txt` through `File2_DDD.txt`, with (e.g.) `File2_BBB.txt` containing:

```
This is the first line:
This is the 2nd line: Some Text Some Text A=BBB
This is the 3rd line: Some Text Some
This is the 4th line: Some Text Some K_XXX Some Text Some
This is the 5th line: DXXX
```

Note that only the first occurrence of `XXX` is replaced because of the `\b` word boundary assertions in the regular expression.

There were two problems with the original script.  The first is it was using `sed -i` to do the replacement on the same file rather than creating a new one, as was noted in a comment.

The other was the single quoting in the argument to `sed`, which prevents expansion of `$line`.  I used double quoting instead.

Comment: Scott Thank you so much for the explanation. What I need to do if I want the script to replace all the occurrences ?  I need to get rid of \b ? if so how the modified sed command will look like ?

Comment: Right, just remove both occurrences of `\b`.  The `sed` command is otherwise the same: `sed "s/XXX/$line/g" < file2.txt > "File2_$line.txt"`.

Comment: Thanks Sir ... Stay Safe... 